# dfply - Python - X name is undefined

Tags: python, dfply

I'm using package `dfply` in python which mimics the package `dplyr` in R.
This is the simple code I'm trying to run. I have this dataset 'data' previously loaded in my environment and I just want to group for that variable.

```
    import dfply as dp
    data['CO_SPORTELLO']=data['CO_SPORTELLO'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
    data=(data >> 
          dp.group_by(X.CO_SPORTELLO))
```

The error I keeping getting is: `NameError: name 'X' is not defined`.

From the package documentation:

> The DataFrame as it is passed through the piping operations is
>   represented by the symbol X. It records the actions you want to take
>   (represented by the Intention class), but does not evaluate them until
>   the appropriate time. Operations on the DataFrame are deferred.
>   Selecting two of the columns, for example, can be done using the
>   symbolic X DataFrame during the piping operations.

```
diamonds >> select(X.carat, X.cut) >> head(3)

   carat      cut
0   0.23    Ideal
1   0.21  Premium
2   0.23     Good
```

Comment: well, you aren't defining `X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `from dfply import *`; that should define `X`.

Either that or replace `X` with `dp.X` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use 'dp.group_by' just 'group_by' would works.